# Getting Python program error: x is not defined

Tags: python

I made a program in python to calculate the roots of a quadratic equation by asking user for the coefficients.When I run the program for D>0, it is fine but for D<0 , it is printing imaginary solution but I am also getting the error : x is not defined. I want to remove that.I tried many other loops also but since I am a beginner at my own so I got struck , please help

```
import math

a=int(input("Enter a:"))
b=int(input("Enter b:"))
c=int(input("Enter c:"))

D = b * b - 4* a* c

if D < 0:
    print("imaginary solution")

if D >= 0:
    x = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)

y =- b/a - x

print(x, y)
```

Comment: Indentation problem: all the code referring to `x` should be indented to be inside the `if D >= 0:` block.

Answer (score 1):

x is only defined when D >= 0, you have to either also define x when D < 0, or skip any code including x.

```
Import math
a = int(input("Enter a:")) 
b = int(input("Enter b:")) 
c = int(input("Enter c:"))

D = b * b - 4 * a * c

if D < 0:
    print("imaginary solution")
else:
    x = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
    y = -b/a - x
    print(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that x is assigned (and defined) only in a specific case,
one solution is to define it at the start of the program, as:
`x=0`